# What does this nested annotation do / allow?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations, spring-validator

I was looking at the `@org.hibernate.validator.constaints.NotEmpty` annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1)
public @interface NotEmpty {
    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    /**
     * Defines several {@code @NotEmpty} annotations on the same element.
     */
    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface List {
        NotEmpty[] value();
    }
}
```

I'm confused by the last part:

```
    /**
     * Defines several {@code @NotEmpty} annotations on the same element.
     */
    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface List {
        NotEmpty[] value();
    }
```

I'm not sure how that works, nor how to use it.  From my understanding, anything under Java 8 does not allow repeated annotations on the same element.

Can anybody clarify?

Comment: It is just like a nested static class or nested interface. Use it by `@NotEmpty.List`.

Comment: Nowadays you would use @Repeatable and a container-annotation to achieve the same goal with less verbose code both within the annotation and the thing you're annotating

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reason why [NotEmpty.List](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.List.html) exists, is to go around the fact that same annotation cannot be repeated for same element. With the help of NotEmpty.List multiple [NotEmpty](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html) annotations are effectively applied to one element. Annotation processing checks through the list of NotEmpty annotations that are the value of NotEmpty.List.

In the case of NotEmpty one reason for using List of validators could be use of [groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) and assigning different messages per group.

For the sake of example, let's take entity which can represent either company or person. In both cases name should not be null, but messages differ:

```
@NotEmpty.List({
    @NotEmpty( message = "Person name should not be empty",   
               groups=PersonValidations.class),
    @NotEmpty( message = "Company name should not be empty",    
               groups=CompanyValidations.class),
})
private String name;
```

Comment: That would have to be @NotEmpty.List({ ... }) wouldn't it?